# Moving between classes from product info detailed to product-info-main Magento 2.0

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

I want to move the text from the "more information tab" which is in product info detailed, TO product-info-main under the SKU

So the info usually only seen by pressing the tab MORE INFORMATION is immediately shown.

Any idea's?

Answer (score 0):

I have revied your request Please follow below steps may be it's working

To move **"More Information Tab"** you need to write following code in your

```
(Your Theme > Magento_Catalog > layout  > catalog_product_view.xml)
if file not exist pls copy from Magento installed directory >vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\layout



 <move element="product.attributes" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.price" />
```

Comment: YES ! this does the trick for me, do you also know of a way to place this element just before the price , so it would look like                                 "information blah blah   $12.00" instead of "information blah blah  <new line> $12.00"   By the way thank you very much for the help !

Comment: let me check and get back to you with better solutions